# Selenium ERROR: ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

So I just starting using the Selenium Framework for browser automation. My remote automation is working, however I keep getting the following error:

```
[2944:20700:1219/211513.232:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate
```

My normal Chrome installation 120.0.6099.110 doesn’t throw up any certificate errors. Since I am using Chrome 120.0.6099.110 I went to https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0 which instructed me to go here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

I grabbed chromedriver.exe that matches my web browser and dropped it into my project directory. Then I modified first_script.py to ensure that it calls that specific web driver also commented out the original code:

```
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
service = Service('C:\\py311seleniumbot\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Well it’s using the new chromedriver.exe alright but I’m still getting the same cert error.

Some people on stackoverflow suggest adding:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`
```

Doesn't this just sweep the problem under the rug and result in the Selenium controlled browser connecting to the remote website in an insecure manner? Proper https security needs to be happening.

Someone in the following reddit thread suggested "Most likely an expired ca public cert in the browsers cert store. so please update the browser and webdriver you use." :

https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/xpgx4o/error_message_that_just_doesnt_have_a_solution/

But they don't explain how to do that? I thought I downloaded the webdriver that is remote controlling the default chrome install on my PC, but now I'm wondering if it's spawning some different old version of chrome? How can I tell and fix this? I'm using Windows 10, and I am fine with working with the command line if needed.

Comment: when you browse manually to the site and check the details on the signature, does it show any issues?

Comment: My apologies for not making this clear in my initial post. No the signature shows no issue when I browse manually.